# Variable not Updating until I Print it out?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've made an infinite while loop that checks if a boolean is ever changed(I have a button in JFrame that make a false boolean true). However, even though I'm checking every tick, it only works if I print out the variable.

I'm pretty sure that the program doesnt update the variable unless I print it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Code:

```
  while (100 == 100) {
   System.out.println(panelVar.getGen() == false);
   boolean make = panelVar.getGen();
   //System.out.println(make);
   if (make != false) {
    System.out.println(sentenceMaker(minLength, wordAmt, sourceTxt));
    //panelVar.setGen(false);
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please post some code (a [mcve]) that demonstrates your problem.  Otherwise we can only speculate.

Comment: try making it `volatile`

Comment: nit: `while(true)` or `for(;;)` works too

Comment: It gives me Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field SentenceGeneratorPanel.gen

Comment: Then run the code outside of your main method as an instance method

Comment: Also I suggest you never compare booleans to `true` or `false` it looks bad and can cause a difficult to find bug if you use `=` instead of `==`

Comment: I suggest you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html and more generally https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: whats `sentenceMaker()`, see if you can print out the individual arguments for that function call within the if statement after checking the boolean condition.

Answer (score 0):

GUIs are never supposed to run infinite loops on the main thread. This makes them lock-up, and will not respond, which might explain why your variable is not showing up.

You should use callbacks like `ActionListener` to notify external widgets of changes. You can also use `AtomicBoolean` for multi-threaded access

Otherwise, you are seeing race-conditions and should be running that loop in a separate `Thread`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did my code really idiotically, but I basically made two files. One for my JFrame which has the listener. When I click on the button the listener updates a boolean in my JFrame file. Then, in my main file, I have a loop constantly waiting and checking if the boolean got updated. I don't know any better way of doing it. Also I'm kind of new to Java and suck.

Comment: I usually also make a class file for a Frame and another for JPanels. Then another fille with main method. Maybe another for each button action... My point is that number of files is _not_ a problem

Comment: @EthanJhong Think of the button as an event. Then you send a "notification"... in IRL, when you get a text message, there is not an infiinite loop in your phone constantly seeing if somebody texted you

Comment: I would suggest making a new question and a  [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

> Then, in my main file, I have a loop constantly waiting and checking if the boolean got updated.

You should not have a loop in your main file.

Instead you define a method like `setMake(Boolean make)` in you main file

> When I click on the button the listener updates a boolean in my JFrame file.

So instead of updating the boolean directly, you invoke the `setMake(…)`. Then in the setMake(….) method you change the state of the Boolean variable and do any special processing.